# Functions of adjectives

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, attributive-nouns, predicate

> It was cloudy this morning.

The word cloudy in this sentence is for sure an adjective. However, what is its syntactic function?

> is it an:
>
> object complement adjective
>
> or a predicate adjective
>
> or a attributive adjective

Comment: It was a cloudy morning. He was funny. He was a funny guy. A regular adjective. You are asking about function.

Comment: So, what is its function? is it predicate or regular?

Comment: It's a  predicate adjective but I warn you that others have fancier names for this.

Comment: I have to admit, I often don't understand what questions about "syntactic function" are trying to get at. "It" obviously is a pronoun for "the sky." "The sky was cloudy" uses the adjective cloudy to describe the sky. Does the answer have to be an Latin or something? (only being a bit facetious)?

Comment: @user8356 Well, if you take a look at ze ozzer site, you will see that often it does have to be Greek to common mortals who otherwise are quite educated. :)